# antd component links not to its own but dependency's props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

There is a problem with antd component (e.g. `TreeSelect`, but also saw it on other components as well). We have project as package with some sub-projects (-packages).

In a sub project when placing some antd components e.g. `TreeSelect` and picking props, it provides different props, than when using those components in main project (ant versions are the same or can be differnet by one or two patch versions).

The problem that I see is when inspecting `TreeSelect` props in sub project it links correctly to antd lib in node modules, but in the main project (that imports the sub-project) it wrongly links to rc-select lib, which is the underlaying package of antd. That leads to random behavior, because rc-select has partly different properties.

`TreeSelect` in sub-project, marking `dropdownClassName` prop as deprecated and suggesting using `popupClassName` instead

[image]

Same code in main project, `popupClassName` is not recognized as correct prop, `dropdownClassName` is not marked as deprecated.

[image]

[image]

Imports are the same in both cases (same code in both cases)
[image]

Comment: it sounds like you're either passing implicitly the props to the TreeSelect or you're wrong about your imports, either way upload the code

Comment: @TzachiElrom import is the same in both cases, if it would be wrong then it would not work either way. Ok I will update with some screenshots